# Unity 3D | Is there any option to import a 3D model and use it in a existing player object?

Tags: unity-game-engine, character, 3d-model

is there any option to import a 3D model and use it in a existing player object?
I have already got a player object and I want to use my 3D object as the model of it. 
Can I do this, or must I move all the things to the new object?

(Sorry for the not perfect english)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just drag your 3D model in to the scene and make it child of the player object. You can do that simply by dragging the model object on top of the player object in `Hierarchy`. If you already have a model for player object (e.g. default cube model) than you can delete the `Mesh Renderer` from `Inspector`.